# Array declaration difference

Tags: arrays, swift

If you have a minute; I'm struggling to understand the difference between those two declaration. I know the first one is to create a new empty array of type string so is the second to declare an already existing array of type string ? Thank you

```
var array = [String] ()    

var array:[String] = []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between those declarations - both will create empty string array

Comment: Ok thank you. The wonders of coding :)